# How to manually get an instance of provider outside of Nest.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs

I have an Express.js application that I'm migrating to Nest.js, some application modules are using Nest.js, some aren't.

Let's say I have an OrderModule which is a Nest.js module and it has an OrderService in its providers and I would like to use OrderService in a product module that is not a NestJS module.
Is it possible to get an instance of OrderService without converting the product module to a NestJS module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get access to Nest's DI container from outside the application would be to export the `app` instance created by `NestFactory.create()` and then call `app.get(OrderService)` to retrieve the service.

Comment: Is there a way to get all the providers at once? I want to get all providers that are subclasses of a particular class, and I believe the `get()` API is insufficient for my use case. Separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773524/is-there-an-easy-way-to-retrieve-all-subclass-instances-of-a-base-class-from-nes/72775585#72775585

Answer (score -2):

It's just an example for include 'apn' module (that is not nestjs native)

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserGateway } from '../../users/gateways/user.gateway';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationsGateway {
    private user: UserGateway;
    private appleapn = require('apn');
...
```

Comment: The question isn't about general npm modules, it's about getting a Nest service outside of the Nest DI context

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).